# Set method arguments by their name?

Tags: java, json

Is it possible to set method arguments by their name, like they do in JavaScript:

Something like:

```
void function(? jsonObject){
    // ...
}
```

And

```
function({ "color": "red", "age": 10 });
```

Or

```
function({ color: "red", age: 10 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. However, there's alternatives:

1. You can use a JSON to Java object library (Jackson, for example). With this approach, you can cast your JSON to an object.
2. If you need Javascript support, you can use the native javascript engine Nashorn.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any  serialization/deserialization library like GSON to for Object to JSON viceversa. Below is a Pojo example.

```
public class Plant{
      private String color;
      private int age;
      //Getter and Setter
      //toString() implement as you want
    }
 private void displayPlant(Plant plant){
      System.out.println(plant)
    }
```

Please let me know if you need more details on GSON.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can read JSON as String object and then parse into valid object OR Map like:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;


void function(String jsonObject){
   YourClass obj = mapper.readValue(jsonObject, YourClass.class);
   System.out.println(obj);

}
```